# script tag hack + how do I communicate after the second level of AJAX

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, disqus

I want to provide an embeddable javascript which will get a script from my server . Which in turn will get some details from the user(the page which which has my embeddable js) and put it back onto my server . How do i go about achieving this .

This is the embeddable js i provide .

```
  <script>
        (function() {
            read="This is the data which is entered by the user"; 
            var istreet = document.createElement('script'); istreet.type = 'text/javascript'; istreet.async = true;
            istreet.src = 'http://xyz.com/a.php;
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(istreet);
        })();

    </script>
```

And this is the code on http://xyz.com/a.php

```
$('<div id="content"></div>').appendTo('body');
$('#content').html('
    Some html to inject to the page\'s dom . 
');
$.get("http://xyz.com/process.php?dataToProcess="+read,function(data){
alert(data);
});
```

But I see that the $.get("http://xyz.com/process.php?dataToProcess="+read,function(data){
// leads to a cross domain ajax request

I do not want to solve the cross domain ajax problem .
I want to be able to communicate between the two parties(the one with the embeddable script and my server) seamlessly .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this the cross domain iframe hack to commmunicate between the two different domain . I recommend reading this

http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is a GET request, you can use JSON-P(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP).

In your JavaScript, the syntax would be something like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://xyz.com/process.php?dataToProcess=" + encodeURIComponent(read) + "&callback=?",
   function(result){
     alert(result);
   });
```

The "callback=?" property tells JQuery that this is a JSON-P request.  JQuery will substitute some arbitrary string for the "?" (more details here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

To make this work properly, you also need to change your process.php handler.  The PHP handler should first read the value of the "callback" query parameter, and then wrap the response in that value.

For example, if $.getJSON() sends the parameter "callback=abcd" to the php page, the php page should return:

```
abcd({"data": "json object with the result"});
```

A few things to note:

- Be sure to escape any user data you send to the server using encodeURIComponent();
- If process.php modifies user data, you should be careful when using GET requests, as that could lead to XSRF attacks (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).